# WebApi Attri8bute Bases Routing for .NET 4.0/ source code

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes

I would like to use Attribute Based Routing in a WebApi project based on .NET 4.0 (due to deployment environment restrictions) so having to stay tied to WeApi 1. Is there any possibility for doing this?

Former, the source code used to stay somewhere on git (before including this as feature of the upcoming WebApi) - I am interested also on this because probably we will have to customize further the routing for route versioning reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still get an [old version of AttributeRouting](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting) on GitHub, but it probably isn't as up-to-date as the functionality you get in WebApi2.